# Dividing into fractors in C#

Tags: c#

Simple question I think, I am a little unsure as to why

```
decimal currentPercentage = 0;

currentPercentage = currentPercentage*((decimal)1 / (decimal)daysPerYear--);//or
currentPercentage *= ((decimal)1 / (decimal)daysPerYear--);
```

Will return 0 everytime but

```
(decimal)1 / (decimal)daysPerYear--;
```

will return the decimal I am after. What am I missing here?

Comment: The previous posters all solved your problem, but I cant resist to offer some personal suggestions: Consider looking over your types so you don't have to cast everything all the time. For the literal 1, use 1M to make it a decimal. Also, using the decrement operator (--) within a calculation is rather error prone. Your code would probably benefit it you decremented in a separate statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're multiplying by 0.

*`currentPercentage`* is *`0`* before computing:

```
currentPercentage = currentPercentage*((decimal)1 / (decimal)daysPerYear--);
```

So you have in fact:

```
currentPercentage = 0 * ((decimal)1 / (decimal)daysPerYear--);
```

This expression is *`0`* no matter what *`((decimal)1 / (decimal)daysPerYear--)`* is :)

Answer (score 1):

Set `decimal currentPercentage = 1;` as you would be multiplying by 0 in your case. 1 is the neutral element in multiplication, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't want to sum, not multiply, the percentages.  If you're doing this in a loop and accumulating percentages, summing would be more appropriate. If you really are going to multiply, you need to start with 1, not zero.

BTW, you really should be using decimal constants, rather than casting an integer constant to decimal.

```
var currentPercentage = 0M;
currentPercentage += (1M / (decimal)daysPerYear--);
```

or

```
var currentPercentage = 1M;
currentPercentage *= (1M / (decimal)daysPerYear--);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal currentPercentage = 0;
```

No matter what you multiply with zero, the result will be zero...